# Combine some arrays with a order

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

For Example, I have four links in following variable:

```
$content = "

http://example.com/folder/Name.S01E01.720p.mp4
http://example.com/folder/Name.S01E02.720p.mp4

http://example.com/folder/Name.S02E01.480p.mp4
http://example.com/folder/Name.S02E02.480p.mp4

";
```

In the up variable, I want to create an order according to a few words:

```
Season template is S00
And
Episode template is E00
And
Quality template is 720p and 480p
```

So,  i need combine these values to get a result,

i need some function to make $content to something like this:

```
Array
(
    [01] => //Season Number
    (
        [720p] =>//Quality Name
            (
                [URLs] => //Full Url's
                    (
                        [0] => http://example.com/folder/Name.S01E01.720p.mp4
                        [1] => http://example.com/folder/Name.S01E02.720p.mp4
                    )

            )

    )

[02] => //Season Number
    (
        [480p] => //Quality Name
            (
                [URLs] => //Full Url's
                    (
                        [0] => http://example.com/folder/Name.S02E01.480p.mp4
                        [1] => http://example.com/folder/Name.S02E02.480p.mp4
                    )

            )

    )

)
```

I hope you understand what I mean.

please look this:

```
$content = "

http://example.com/folder/Name.S01E01.720p.mp4
http://example.com/folder/Name.S01E02.720p.mp4

http://example.com/folder/Name.S02E01.480p.mp4
http://example.com/folder/Name.S02E02.480p.mp4

";


if(preg_match_all('/(https?:\/\/[^ ]+?(?:\.mkv|\.mp4))/ms', $content, $matches)){
    foreach($matches[0] as $link){
        if(preg_match('/(\d++(p))/i',$link,$q)){
            $quality[] = $q[0];
        }
        $full_url[] = trim(urldecode($link));
    }
}

if(preg_match_all('/(S(\d++)E(\d++))/i', $content, $parts)){
    foreach($parts[0] as $part){
         $season[]  = $part[2];
    }
}

//var_dump($quality);
//var_dump($full_url);
//var_dump($season);
```

i want combine $season with $full_url and $quality.

Comment: So if you have `Name5.S01E01.720p.mp4` and `Name10.S01E01.720p.mp4` do you want them in the same array or their own?  You don't show that in result.

Comment: No. i edited the first post, please look again

Comment: Working on GOT series-wise folder creation? ;)

Answer (score 1):

I added the name part as the first level and the episode number instead of a dynamic index for each URL, if you don't want them then just use `$result[$m[2]][$m[4]]['URLs'][] = $url;`.  I also left out the `.mp4` part in case you have other extensions:

```
$lines = array_filter(explode("\n", $content));
foreach($lines as $url) {
    preg_match('/^([^.]+)\.S(\d\d)E(\d\d)\.(\d+p)/', pathinfo($url, PATHINFO_BASENAME), $m);
    $result[$m[1]][$m[2]][$m[4]]['URLs'][$m[3]] = $url;
}
```

- Split the contents on line endings and filter out the blank lines
- Loop the lines and match the pieces you want from the base filename
- Build a multi-dimensional array using those matches

Given your `$content` this will yield the following:

```
Array
(
    [Name] => Array
        (
            [01] => Array
                (
                    [720p] => Array
                        (
                            [URLs] => Array
                                (
                                    [01] => http://example.com/folder/Name.S01E01.720p.mp4
                                    [02] => http://example.com/folder/Name.S01E02.720p.mp4
                                )
                        )
                )
            [02] => Array
                (
                    [480p] => Array
                        (
                            [URLs] => Array
                                (
                                    [01] => http://example.com/folder/Name.S02E01.480p.mp4
                                    [02] => http://example.com/folder/Name.S02E02.480p.mp4
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

- Match from the beginning `^` and capture one or more `+` non dot `[^.]` characters
- Then match a dot `\.` the letter `S` and capture two digits `\d\d`
- Then match the letter `E` and capture two digits `\d\d`
- Then match a dot `\.` and capture one or more digits `\d+` and the `p` character

Comment: some impressive regular expression magic there.  I'm not going to bother posting my answer now, that's pretty great.